# Salesforce: Parsing JSON with Apex using REST callout and JSON2Apex

Tags: json, parsing, salesforce, apex

Hoping somebody can help me.

I am relatively new to apex code (previously a system admin)- so sincere apologies for anything simple I may have missed!. I am trying to parse json from a REST callout into my dev org utilising the JSON2APEX tool. My Classes are as below:

```
public class JSON2Apex {
    public Boolean success;
    public String message;
    public List<Result> result;

public class Result {
    public String MarketCurrency;
    public String BaseCurrency;
    public String MarketCurrencyLong;
    public String BaseCurrencyLong;
    public Double MinTradeSize;
    public String MarketName;
    public Boolean IsActive;
    public String Created;
    public Object Notice;
    public Object IsSponsored;
    public String LogoUrl;
}

public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
    return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
}
}

Public Class GetBittrexCoins{
public static HttpResponse makeGetCallout(){
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets');
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
// If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
JSON2Apex p = JSON2Apex.parse(response.getBody());
System.debug(p);
}
return response;
}
}
```

Nothing appears in my System.debug for the json body - so I am clearly doing something wrong. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you get response with status code 200 (OK)? If it's not, JSON parsing is not invoked at all. Try to add 'System.debug();' before 'if' statement and check response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply- I added System.debug(response) before the IF statement and there is nothing in the debug log. Would this mean the response is not being returned?

Comment: Possibly, it's related to debug log settings, check out [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139902/system-debug-not-displaying-in-debug-logs)

Comment: Thanks - I tried another http request and was able to view debug logs- so looks like this may not be the problem. I am thinking maybe something is wrong with the way I am doing the callout

Comment: Make sure that you registered your endpoint on Salesforce Remote Site Settings page. [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts) you can find more details.